# C# and SQL Server: How do I get values from my SQL Table, by calling my stored procedure with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, google-maps, stored-procedures

I created the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetPoint
AS
    SELECT point FROM tLocalGeo
```

Now I need execute that procedure from my C# Controller and save the data on a list.

As you can see the context of the problem is to get points so then I can display them on google map using javascript for that.

Can you give me some reference how to do it? Do I need SQLReader?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SqlDataAdapter** and **DataSet** and then can get values from dataset's first table.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("store procedure Name", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
if(ds.Tables[0]!=null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //your code
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond.
I'm returning ds object to my view, is that possible? So then i can make a foreach statement in my script to display all markers on google map.

return View(ds);

Comment: Yes you can return DataSet to View and you can also convert into list and can pass that list to View. See For Data set to View http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727107/how-to-pass-ado-net-dataset-to-a-view

Comment: @M.Coutinho: still any confusion?

Comment: No thank you, i just have another problem here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557568/c-sharp-asp-net-mvc-project-and-google-maps-how-to-fill-javascript-array-with-v

Comment: @M.Coutinho: Develop habit of accepting answers if they work for you that way you can also increase response to your questions

Comment: Yes, completly forgot about it! Sorry for that! Thank you for your help, was truly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
  String strConnString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection con =  new SqlConnection(strConnString);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.CommandText = "GetPoint";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Empid)   // ur input parameter//
  cmd.Connection = con;
   try
   {
  con.Open();
  GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
  GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader() ;
  GridView1.DataBind(); 
   }
```