# C# ASP.NET MVC Project and Google Maps: How to fill JavaScript array with values from C# List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have a Class like this:

```
public class Markers
    {
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }

        //Constructors and Methods
        //(...)
    }
```

On my Controller I have an ActionResult with a List of Markers and I add latitude and longitude like this

```
 List<Markers> listM = new List<Markers>(); //NOTE: this is outside of my ActionResult, no problem with that.
 //(...)
 listM.Add(new Markers(value[0], value[1])); //NOTE: value[0] is my lat and value[1] is my longitude
 //(...)
```

And at the end i return my list to the View:

```
return (listM);
```

Now on the View, I need to access the data and fill an array so I can display the markers on my google map.

**How to fill the array with markers in position lat, long from my list?**

```
@using ProjectName.Models
@model List<Markers>

<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>...</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//How can I add a GoogleMap Marker ?
var markersArray = [];
@foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                      //can't use google.maps.Marker inside this foreach =(
                }

</script>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** This is how I add a marker on that array with a click on the map.

```
function addMarker(location) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: location,
                    title: 'Bomb',
                    map: map,
                    icon: bomb
                });
                markersArray.push(marker);
            }
```

Question 2:
Markers still doesn't show on map after @Leo Solution!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var geocoder;
            var markersArray = [];
            var geoMarker;

            var bomb = new google.maps.MarkerImage('Content/Images/Pins/bomb.png',           
            new google.maps.Size(32, 37), 
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
            new google.maps.Point(22, 44) 
            );



            function initialize() {


                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.287739, -7.738992),
                    zoom: 16,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                };


                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);


                @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                    <text>
                    var locations = google.maps.LatLng('@item.latitude', '@item.longitude', false);
                addMarker(locations);
                   </text>
                }



                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
                    markersArray[i].setMap(map);
                }


                geoMarker = new GeolocationMarker(map);
                geoMarker.setCircleOptions({ fillColor: '#808080' });
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(geoMarker, 'position_changed', function () {
                    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(geoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function (e) {
                    alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
                });

                geoMarker.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                    addMarker(event.latLng);
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

                    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();           
                    //map.setCenter(myLatLng);
                    document.getElementById('mapzoom').innerHTML = 'Zoom: ' + zoomLevel;
                });


            }


            function showAddress() {
                alert("Vai navegar para outro endereço!");
                var address = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: mp,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('error: ' + status);
                    }
                });

            }


            function addMarker(location) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: location,
                    title: 'Bomba',
                    map: map,
                    icon: bomb
                });
                markersArray.push(marker);
            }


            function setAllMap(map) {
                for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
                    markersArray[i].setMap(map);
                }
            }


            function clearMarkers() {
                setAllMap(null);
            }

            function showMarkers() {
                setAllMap(map);
            }


            function deleteMarkers() {
                clearMarkers();
                markersArray = [];
            }


            function loadScript() {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
                    'callback=initialize';
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            window.onload = loadScript;


            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
            }


        </script>
```

Comment: well constructed question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.....

```
 <script>
    var markersArray = [];
    var _map = null;
    var _c = null;


    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
         <text>
             markersArray.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                 draggable: true,
                 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng('@item.latitude', '@item.longitude', false),
                 title: 'Whatever title',
                 map: _map
             }));
         </text>
     }
 </script>
```

#### Second Question

I had to carefully look at your code and found 3 problems...one of them you've already mentioned it. The other ones are that you are duplicating variable names and you are not instantiating a new object. Now change this....

```
      @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <text>
                var locations = google.maps.LatLng('@item.latitude', '@item.longitude', false);
            addMarker(locations);
               </text>
            }
```

to this....

```
        @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <text>
            addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('@item.latitude'), parseFloat('@item.longitude')));
               </text>
            }
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Can't use var location, but i changed it to another name. Markers doesn't show on map. Maybe because im not initializing map with them, ill check that.

Comment: Well, I was actually trying to provide some guidance of how to use razor syntax inside a script block, you still have to adjust this code. I'll update it for you

Comment: Well i think i have some problem with my data! It works now, but with other values! Example:

"var locations = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);"

Your help was truly useful, thank you! It seems I need to understand better how to work with coordinates. Thank you sir!

Comment: Google Map doesn't show markers when i add values from my model item.longitude and item.latitude. Do you have any ideas why? Already created an alert('item.longitude') and the value is correct :S

Comment: I noticed you are using the experimental version and after reviewing the documentation I cannot find any MarkerImage object in the documentation reference. It doesn't exist

Comment: Are you using any plug-ins?

Comment: That works fine, because if I have something like this : "var locations = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);" A custom marker is displayed on map. I don't think that is the problem. Im not using any extension.

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't work fine if it's not rendering your markers. Point One: GeolocationMarker, this is NOT defined in google's api is a plugin, check this out (https://github.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/blob/master/geolocationmarker/examples/mylocation.html). Point TWO: google.maps.MarkerImage is not defined either!!!! Read this...https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/D-7uLsch28c). Anyway, I already answer your original question, happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Even if i remove that, still not working, so the problem isnt with that! 

I got those code from https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Same for GeolocationMarker

Comment: Ithink i've found the problem, somehow my value is for example "46,342" and i need exacly 46.342 Its changing from point to comma, and that doesn't work when using markers on google maps. How can I force a point?

Comment: Leo couldn't do that otherwise i would loose some important values after comma. I have another solution like using .replace(',','.')

Thank you for your help! It now works perfectly! Best regards